# Coherent sheaves on a noetherian affine scheme are always globally generated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Assume $X$ is a Noetherian affine scheme, and $F$ be an $O_X$-module. I just want to check if this is obvious that $F$ is coherent implies generated by global sections. It looks right to me from definition but can't find any reference though.

Comment: I guess you mean $X$ is a Noetherian *scheme*?  In any case this is false--why do you think it is true?

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry my bad, just change the question, is this true if X is affine?

Comment: Then it is true.  Whether it is "obvious" depends on what definition of "coherent" you are using and what theorems you know.

Comment: If coherent implies quasicoherent, then this is true and you don't need to assume that $X$ is Noetherian. On any affine scheme $X$ the category of quasicoherent sheaves is equivalent to the category of modules over $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm using the definition of locally finitely presented. I'm stll confused when X is not affine, that in the definition it is said F is finitely presented over any _open set_, not _affine open_. So since X itself as a whole space is open, then $F$ should be finitely presented over X, then it is globally generated (because definition of globally generated is definied as quotient of free modules)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thank you for pointing out that! In my last comment, I am still confused that if we don't require X to be affine, and X itself should be an open set, why F is not necessarily globally generated?

Comment: I'm sure you have seen examples of quasicoherent sheaves on, say the projective line, that have no global sections (other than zero).

Comment: "Locally finitely presented" does not mean that it is finitely presented on *every* open set, just on *some* collection of open sets that cover $X$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, which means there exists _some_ open set around each point where it is finitely generated, but not arbitrary open sets?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you!! I am fooled by other _local_ properties like finiteness and take it for granted. You definitely help me out. Sorry for this stupid question when I am just learning algebraic geometry....